# The type or namespace name 'ProfileCommon' could not be found (in compiler generated code in server)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, profile

I know it has been asked before, but none worked for me and mine is a little bit different.

My MVC 4 project works locally but in server it fails to run with this error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ProfileCommon' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:


Line 194:        }
Line 195:        
Line 196:        protected ProfileCommon Profile {
Line 197:            get {
Line 198:                return ((ProfileCommon)(this.Context.Profile));

Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\e3c4a897\ff4f4317\App_Web_pageheader.ascx.cdcab7d2.rpk2croq.0.cs    Line: 196
```

I have written a custom `ProfileProvider` and configured the project to use it:

```
<profile enabled="true" defaultProvider="sql">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="sql" type="BusinessLogic.ProfileProvider" connectionStringName="c" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
```

I use `ProfileBase` class to access user profile not `ProfileCommon`. The error above is in a compiler generated file. why asp.net generates a code that it can't compile? and why it's working locally?

I have .Net Framework 4.5.1 installed locally but in server it's 4.5 . is it related to the problem?

Answer (score 12):

The same thing occurred for me (although with WebForms with WebAPI services) in our deployment when we moved from a Web Site Project to a Web Application Project.

The solution in our case was to delete PrecompiledApp.config out of the deployed folder on the server, and restart IIS.

Comment: To add what lead to the problem (in my case): I tried using precompiled views.